# Is there any way I can make my discord bot send same messages(without skipping the older messages) in different servers

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm sorry, but i couldn't frame the question properly. Currently when someone uses my "meme" command in one server, it shows the memes however if someone from another server uses the same command,my bot skips the meme it has already shown. I'm new to programming,can someone tell me how to resolve the issue and explain what they did?Thank you!

```
@client.command()
async def meme(ctx, typememe="hot"):
    if typememe == "hot":
    y = next(hot_memes)
    x = y.url
    z = y.title
    votes = y.score
    comments = y.num_comments
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
        title=z,
        url=x
    )

    embed.set_image(
        url=x)
    embed.set_footer(
        text=f"Upvotes:{votes}"
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
elif typememe == "controversial":
    y = next(controversial_memes)
    x = y.url
    z = y.title
    votes = y.score
    comments = y.num_comments
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
        title=z,
        url=x
    )

    embed.set_image(
        url=x)
    embed.set_footer(
        text=f"Upvotes:{votes}"
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Your `hot_memes` is a itertools.cycle object, calling `next` on which causes it to move to the next item in the cycle. So your `hot_memes` behaves like a cycle 1->2->...n->1.
You will have to use a different logic to make sure you get a 'random' each time the command is run ( at least most of the time).

Comment: Oh. Is there a way, I can change this behavior?? Can you suggest some other logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is have a dictionary that stores the guild id and the times the meme command was called, something like `{GUILD_ID,4}` where 4 is the times "meme" was called, we'll call this the memestorage. After that, every time the meme command is called you can check if it in memestorage's keys with `memestorage.keys()` and if it isn't add it with `memestorage[ctx.message.guild] = 0`. Finally, add one to the integer that is at the ctx.message.guild in memestorage and get the meme at that index + 1. All of this together may look something like:

```py
memestorage = {}
memeiter = [meme1,meme2,meme3,meme4]

@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild

    if guild not in memestorage.keys():
        memestorage[guild] = 0

    memestorage[guild] += 1

    if memestorage[guild] >= len(memeiter):
        memestorage[guild] = 1

    pickedmeme = memeiter[memestorage[guild]+1]
```

With this, you could also save the memestorage dict in a json file so you can store the data even when the bot goes offline.